# Combine Points with lines with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot a time series that look like this:

[image]

what I plot with:

```
qplot(Jahr, Wert, data=tu, group = Geschlecht, color = Altersgr) + facet_grid(Geschlecht ~ Land)
```

My data looks like this:

```
  Land   Altersgr Geschlecht Jahr  Wert
1   DE    < 20 J.          m 2000  13.0
2   DE  20-<65 J.          m 2000  25.7
3   DE     65+ J.          m 2000  70.1
4   DE  65-<80 J.          m 2000  44.2
5   DE     80+ J.          m 2000 213.5
6   BB    < 20 J.          m 2000  26.8
```

Everything is fine so far. But I have to connect the corresponding points (same color) with a line. I couldn't figure out how to do that. If I use geom_line() I got this result:

[image]

Which is not what I want... I just have the feeling I overlook something...

Any suggestions? Thanks for y'all help.

Comment: Maybe you wanted `group = Altersgr`?

Comment: What is the exact code that you used to generate the second figure?

Comment: @joran: You're right! setting group = Altersgr and add geom_line() works fine.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra: The code is the one I wrote above: qplot(Jahr, Wert, data=tu, group = Geschlecht, color = Altersgr) + facet_grid(Geschlecht ~ Land)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You may find that using the `group' aes will help you get the result you want.  For example:

```
tu <- expand.grid(Land       = gl(2, 1, labels = c("DE", "BB")),
                  Altersgr   = gl(5, 1, labels = letters[1:5]),
                  Geschlecht = gl(2, 1, labels = c('m', 'w')),
                  Jahr       = 2000:2009)

set.seed(42)
tu$Wert <- unclass(tu$Altersgr) * 200 + rnorm(200, 0, 10)

ggplot(tu, aes(x = Jahr, y = Wert, color = Altersgr, group = Altersgr)) + 
  geom_point() + geom_line() + 
  facet_grid(Geschlecht ~ Land)
```

Which produces the plot found here:

[image]

Comment: It was the groupsetting that was wrong. But thanks for your example!

Answer (score 16):

The following example using the iris dataset works fine:

```
dat = melt(subset(iris, select = c("Sepal.Length","Sepal.Width", "Species")),
      id.vars = "Species")
ggplot(aes(x = 1:nrow(iris), y = value, color = variable), data = dat) +  
      geom_point() + geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: The example throws an error `Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (300): x, y, colour`. How come?

Answer (score 4):

A small change to Paul's code so that it doesn't return the error mentioned above.

```
dat = melt(subset(iris, select = c("Sepal.Length","Sepal.Width", "Species")),
           id.vars = "Species")
dat$x <- c(1:150, 1:150)
ggplot(aes(x = x, y = value, color = variable), data = dat) +  
  geom_point() + geom_line()
```