# Plot thick line with dark dots at data points in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, appearance

I want to plot a path and show where the datapoints are.

[Combine Points with lines with ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8592585/combine-points-with-lines-with-ggplot2)
uses `geom_point() + geom_line()` but I do not like that the dots are much thicker and the lines have a discontinuous look `- x - x ----- x ---` thus I decidet to

#### create my own dotted line:

```
mya <- data.frame(a=1:20)

ggplot() +
  geom_path(data=mya, aes(x=a, y=a, colour=2, size=1)) +
  geom_point(data=mya, aes(x=a, y=a, colour=1, size=1)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(text=element_text(size=11))
```

[image: example of a nice line]

I like that the dots and the line have the same size. I did not use the alpha channel because I fear trouble with the alpha channel when I include the files in other programs.

#### open problems:

- R should not create those legends
- can R calculate the "darker colour" itself? `darker(FF0000) = AA0000`
- how can I manipulate the linethickness? The `size=` parameter did not work as expected in `R 2.15`

Comment: What do you mean by the lines/dots being discontinuous? You mean as in `plot(1:5, type='b')` as opposed to `plot(1:5, type='o')`? (I would have thought discontinuous was the 'b' but ggplot plots with type 'o'?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aesthetics can be set or mapped within a ggplot call.

- An aesthetic defined within aes(...) is mapped from the data, and a legend created.
- An aesthetic may also be set to a single value, by defining it outside aes().

In your case it appears you want to set the size to a single value. You can also use `scale_..._manual(values = ..., guide = 'none')` to suppress the creation of a legend.
This appears to be what you want with `colour`.

You can then use named colours such as `lightblue` and `darkblue` (see `?colors` for more details)

```
ggplot() +
 geom_line(data=mya, aes(x=a, y=a, colour='light'), size = 2) +
 geom_point(data=mya, aes(x=a, y=a, colour='dark'), size = 2) + 
 scale_colour_manual(values = setNames(c('darkblue','lightblue'), 
                                       c('dark','light')), guide = 'none') +
 theme_bw()
```

[image]