# Setting up data for ggplot facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

Data:

[image]

What I would like to do is use `facet_wrap` of four segments where each segment contains three plots with x axis labelled with Month-Year, y axis labelled with the values and the three plots in segment one would be L1, DRP-L1 and OSM-L1, etc.

The top label of each segment would be L1, L2, L3 and L4.  My question is, can I set this up with the data as I've shown above or must I create another column labelled "Location", which would list L1, L2, L3, L4 and each row a value for each location?

This is the code I've generated so far, but (1) I'm unsure how to add the other lines, i.e., DRP_1, OSM_1, etc in each segment; and, (2) I'm not sure why it doesn't plot the zero values?

```
library(ggplot2,scales)
month=rep(c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"),4)
numparts=c(0,   0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  52000,  2000,   0,  0,  0,  0,
           0,   0,  0,  0,  35000,  5000,   0,  20000,  0,  0,  0,  0,
           0,   0,  7500,   17000,  625,    0,  50, 0,  0,  2500,   0,  0,
           0,   0,  250,    0,  1800,   900,    800,    500,    600,    0,  0,  11390)
location=c("Location 1","Location 2","Location 3","Location 4")
data=data.frame(month,numparts,location)

# Faceting
ggplot(data, aes(y=numparts, x=month)) + 
  geom_line( stat="identity") + 
  expand_limits(y=0)+
  scale_x_discrete(labels = month)+
  facet_wrap(~location,scales="free_y")+
  labs(x="Month in 2017",y="Number of Parts")
```

[image]

Comment: Please add code of what you have tried.

Comment: Code added above

Comment: If someone could just tell me how I go about adding the other lines to each segment and how to plot the zero lines I would appreciate it.  I can figure out the rest.,

Answer (score 2):

Your code for the data doesn't match the one in screenshot.

This is an example data by taking first 5 rows from your screenshot:

For adding other lines, you need the group `aes`. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8592585/combine-points-with-lines-with-ggplot2) post.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

val <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 35000,
       0, 0, 7500, 17000, 625, 
       0, 0, 250, 0, 1800,
       1548, 500, 0, 0, 0,
       430, 2857, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

location <-   c(rep("Location 1", 5),
              rep("Location 2", 5),
              rep("Location 3", 5),
              rep("Location 4", 5))

part <- c(rep("L", 20),
          rep("DRP", 20))


data <- data.frame(location, part, val)
data$month <- factor(c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr", "May"), levels = c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr", "May"))


ggplot(data, aes(y = val, x = month, group = part)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = part)) + scale_x_discrete(labels = month) + facet_wrap(~location)
```

[image]