# R ggplot2 qplot - connect the data points with a line

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using the following code to plot in R:

```
q <- qplot(var1, var2, data=data_1)
q + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

which gives me this plot:

[image]

How can I get a line which connects the dots of the various points?

Here are the datasets:

```
> cat(sprintf("\"%s\" \"%f\"\n", data_1$var1, data_1$var2))
"2012Q1" "NA"
 "2012Q2" "NA"
 "2012Q3" "NA"
 "2012Q4" "NA"
 "2013Q1" "81890.091966"
 "2013Q2" "80068.697510"
 "2013Q3" "304742.176778"
 "2013Q4" "223182.661337"
 "2014Q1" "275189.419519"
 "2014Q2" "297179.617112"
 "2014Q3" "284532.546842"
 "2014Q4" "416008.842763"
 "2015Q1" "381822.813657"
 "2015Q2" "410020.242215"
 "2015Q3" "384865.684379"
 "2015Q4" "425738.393387"
 "2016Q1" "382404.239015"
 "2016Q2" "378516.717327"
 "2016Q3" "338451.013178"
 "2016Q4" "351486.235708"
 "2017Q1" "366015.605164"
 "2017Q2" "358818.529895"
 "2017Q3" "325981.821170"
 "2017Q4" "371457.620454"
 "2018Q1" "410345.839819"
 "2018Q2" "398976.425498"
 "2018Q3" "362460.336773"
 "2018Q4" "375626.057926"
 "2019Q1" "361636.409126"
 "2019Q2" "378178.181764"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add `geom_line()`, like:

```
q <- qplot(var1, var2, data=data_1)
q <- q + geom_line(aes(group = 1))
q + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

try using `+ geom_line()`
check this very similar question

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8592585/combine-points-with-lines-with-ggplot2
```